# update a file in node-red through context-storage

Tags: node-red

I have written code to update a file in node-red that works as I want it to. I am not too sure if it is realiable though. When pressing the inject button the current value is stored through context, a file is read and the stored data added to it. What about (a-)synchronicity? What if the stored data becomes larger? maybe the data will not have been stored yet, but the older data is written to the file? is that a possibilty? could i solve this by using some kind of callback function somehow?

here is the node-red code:

[{"id":"ff428878.2bf0d8","type":"inject","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":140,"y":80,"wires":[["d97f4731.48f508"]]},{"id":"aff66bbc.653048","type":"file in","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"","filename":"examplefile.txt","format":"utf8","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"x":380,"y":240,"wires":[["82b889ff.4e5f18"]]},{"id":"216dc166.5c79be","type":"file","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"","filename":"examplefile.txt","appendNewline":true,"createDir":false,"overwriteFile":"true","x":900,"y":80,"wires":[]},{"id":"9238c649.dac2e8","type":"function","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"merge","func":"if(msg.topic == \"new\"){\n    context.set('shortterm', msg.payload);\n    return [null,msg];\n}\n\nif(msg.topic == \"old\"){\n    msg.payload.push(context.get('shortterm'));\n    return [msg,null];\n}\n\n","outputs":"2","noerr":0,"x":611,"y":80,"wires":[["216dc166.5c79be"],["aff66bbc.653048"]]},{"id":"d97f4731.48f508","type":"function","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"mark as new","func":"msg.topic = \"new\";\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":400,"y":80,"wires":[["9238c649.dac2e8"]]},{"id":"10b8938f.1cddfc","type":"function","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"mark as old ","func":"msg.topic = \"old\";\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":810,"y":240,"wires":[["9238c649.dac2e8"]]},{"id":"82b889ff.4e5f18","type":"function","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"JSON parse","func":"if(msg.payload){\n    msg.payload = JSON.parse(msg.payload);\n}\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":610,"y":240,"wires":[["10b8938f.1cddfc"]]},{"id":"7572637c.0a25ac","type":"file","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"","filename":"examplefile.txt","appendNewline":true,"createDir":false,"overwriteFile":"true","x":510,"y":480,"wires":[]},{"id":"1f6b9043.ff153","type":"inject","z":"33a0c3f0.5ad66c","name":"","topic":"","payload":"[]","payloadType":"json","repeat":"","crontab":"25 22 * * *","once":false,"x":210,"y":460,"wires":[["7572637c.0a25ac"]]}]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a single flow to read the file, the next step in the flow will not happen until the file is read.

So your flow is too complex.

```
inject->read file->json node (if the file content is json)->
  function node->write file
```

where the function node:

1. gets the context variable (or creates an empty one if it doesn't exist)
2. Merges the file data with the context
3. writes the context variable
4. changes the `msg.payload` to the updated content
5. `return msg`

Answer (score 0):

Another newer option for persistent file storage with Node-Red 19.0+ is the built in "context storage".

There is a nice write up on how to get rolling with context storage here:

https://discourse.nodered.org/t/a-guide-to-understanding-persistent-context/4115

The basics are to update your ***~/.node-red/settings.js*** file with contextStorage settings:

`contextStorage: {
    default  : { module: "memory" },
    fileStore: { module: "localfilesystem"}
},`

From there you can reference in your flows:

```
flow.set("jsObj", "Hello there!", "fileStore");
```

To get data back out:

```
flow.get("jsObj", "fileStore")
```

At which point you can see your saved file within your ***~/.node-red/context/*** folder.

The linked article above should be able to answer any other questions.